# PHP script that can calculate average of columns in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need some help on how to code my php script so that it will find the average of six columns in mysql database and store the new results in a new column inside the mysql database.

For example

the MSQL Database has the following columns

```
 Name    EXAM1       EXAM2     EXAM3    EXAM4    EXAM5
```

Then the following records are entered into the dataabse

```
 Name    EXAM1       EXAM2     EXAM3    EXAM4    EXAM5


Eric     10          20        10        20       10
```

Then the PHP script will generate this result

```
 Name    EXAM1       EXAM2     EXAM3    EXAM4    EXAM5     AVERAGE


Eric     10          20        10        20       10         14
```

So that in the MYSQL database, the records will show just like the PHP script results.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Revise your design. You should have three columns: user_id, exam_id, score

Comment: I agree with @Strawberry. Also, you don't need PHP to calculate averages. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787561/find-the-average-of-two-combined-columns-in-sql

Answer (score 1):

You can do it direct in SQL like

```
UPDATE yourTable set AVERAGE = (EXAM1+EXAM2+EXAM3+EXAM4+EXAM5)/5;
```

Or you automatic generate the AVERAGE if you define your table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable (
  title VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  exam1 DOUBLE,
  exam2 DOUBLE,
  exam3 DOUBLE,
  exam4 DOUBLE,
  exam5 DOUBLE,
  average DOUBLE GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((exam1 + exam2 + exam3 + exam4 + exam5) / 5 ) STORED
);
```

**sample**

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE yourTable (
    ->   title VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   exam1 DOUBLE,
    ->   exam2 DOUBLE,
    ->   exam3 DOUBLE,
    ->   exam4 DOUBLE,
    ->   exam5 DOUBLE,
    ->   average DOUBLE GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((exam1 + exam2 + exam3 + exam4 + exam5) / 5 ) STORED
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,02 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO yourTable (title, exam1, exam2, exam3, exam4, exam5)
    -> VALUES('test1',1,1,22,33,44),('Test2',333,24,11,45,97);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0,00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
mysql> SELECT * FROM yourTable;
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+
| title | exam1 | exam2 | exam3 | exam4 | exam5 | average |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+
| test1 |     1 |     1 |    22 |    33 |    44 |    20.2 |
| Test2 |   333 |    24 |    11 |    45 |    97 |     102 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: thanks for the help. However, I get this error when I tried to follow the code you gave above.  == #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((exam1 + exam2 + exam3 + exam4 + exam5) / 5 ) STORED )' at line 8

Comment: which version you have installed **select version();**