# How to calculate average of a SQL Column in php by Group Id and display on HTML Page?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to calculate the Average value of all other columns grouping them by collegename. 
i.e RVCE with Average of all other columns, 
    BMS with Average of all other columns and so on
and display the value in HTML.

[SQL Database Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2dV0.png)

I have tried the following code in but it is returning me no values.

```
<?php
$hostname="localhost:8889";
$username="root";
$password="root";
$db = "rank";
$dbh = new PDO("MySQL:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT collegename,AVG(campus)  
FROM college       
GROUP BY collegename') as $row) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['AVG(campus)'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Does the raw query work fine in mySQL?

Comment: I got the error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use nea 'SELECT collegename AVG(campus) AS avg_campus  FROM college GROUP BY collegename' at line 2

Comment: Data type for campus column?

Comment: All are int(11)  except collegename

Comment: Can you recreate the error in SQLFiddle or in rextester? The syntax is correct, there must be something else going on...

Comment: Silly question - are you running in mySQL with the single quotes?

Comment: Yes it Words on SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6abec/3 and What if i want to do for each column?

Comment: ok, so now try this in php and see if that goes ok

Comment: No it's not working in PHP

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Check here http://rank.bsid.io/sq.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one?

```
<?php
$hostname="127.0.0.1";
$port=8889;
$username="root";
$password="root";
$db = "rank";
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$db;host=$hostname;port=$port", $username, $password);
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT collegename,AVG(campus) AS avg_campus  
FROM college       
GROUP BY collegename') as $row) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['collegename'] . " AVG: " . $row['avg_campus'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: @SiD even `collegename` is blank?

Comment: Yes, Nothing is displayed

Comment: @SiddharthaB ok try the updated one, added port and using `127.0.0.1` as host (should be the same as local host), also `mysql` using lowercase

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
     AVG((campus + location + cost + internet + safety + placement + hapiness + weather + fun + fests)/10) as avg_campus,
   FROM
     college
   GROUP BY
     collegename
```

If you have only one row for a college name, then the group by is useless and... the AVG() as well

For average of each individual column :

```
SELECT AVG(campus) as campus, AVG(location) as location, AVG(cost) as cost, AVG(internet) as internet, AVG(safety) as safety, AVG(placement) as placement, AVG(hapiness) as hapiness, AVG(weather) as weather, AVG(fun) as fun, AVG(fests) as fests
FROM college 
GROUP BY collegename
```

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787561/find-the-average-of-two-combined-columns-in-sql can be usefull for you to read

Comment: I want to calculate average of each individual column not a combined value

Comment: Then for average of each individual column :
`SELECT
         AVG(campus) as campus, AVG(location) as location, AVG(cost) as cost, AVG(internet) as internet, AVG(safety) as safety, AVG(placement) as placement, AVG(hapiness) as hapiness, AVG(weather) as weather, AVG(fun) as fun, AVG(fests) as fests
       FROM
         college
       GROUP BY
         collegename`