# How to calculate the average value in this table

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am getting the table values dynamically with the using of php and codeigniter now i need to calculate the average value based on two rows.Please provide me the sql query for this.

Sql,php codeigniter and Apache

```
SELECT [current].refuel_master_id, [current].kms_reading,  
       ISNULL([next].kms_reading, 0) - [current].kms_reading
FROM refuel_master AS [current] LEFT JOIN
     refuel_master AS [next]
     ON [next].refuel_master_id = (SELECT MIN(refuel_master_id) 
                                   FROM refuel_master 
                                   WHERE refuel_master_id > [current].refuel_master_id
                                  )
```

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hello, as a new contributor of SO I would suggest to read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and try to edit your question in order to be more suitable for SO. Thanks and welcome!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787561/find-the-average-of-two-combined-columns-in-sql Check this

Comment: @Nagireddysridevi . . . I don't understand what you are calculating.  What rows?  What is the calculation?